# Facebook Login Button not appearing in ui-view child

Tags: facebook, angularjs, angularjs-directive, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm making an AngularJS app with the facebook sdk. The structure comes as follows:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
    <title>Reportes para Anunciantes</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <!-- more scripts here -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : 'MYAPPID', //Have an actual app id in my source
                cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                // the session
                xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
                version    : 'v2.0' // use version 2.0
            });

            angular.bootstrap(document, ['Application']);
        };

        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/sdk.js";

            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
    <div id="content" ui-view>
        Cargando API de Facebook ...
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the page, I load Angular once the Facebook API is loaded. The site uses `xfbml` for the login buttons.

The whole angular app is in index.js:

```
var Application = angular.module(
    "Application",
    ['ui.router'],
    ['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider){
        //$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
        $stateProvider
            .state('notloggedin', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/notloggedin.html',
                controller: 'Application.NotLoggedIn'
            })
            .state('notauthorized', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/notauthorized.html',
                controller: 'Application.NotAuthorized'
            })
            .state('inapp', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/inapp.html',
                controller: 'Application.InApp'
            });
    }]
);

function FBStatusChecker($state){
    this._state = $state;
}
FBStatusChecker.prototype = {
    checkAndGo: function(response) { /* omitted - no issue here */ },
    /* omitted methods - no issue here */
    updateState: function(){
        var context = this;
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            context.checkAndGo(response);
        })
    }
};
Application.StatusChangeService = Application.service('Application.FBStatusChecker', ['$state', FBStatusChecker]);

Application.directive("fbLoginButton", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            console.log("your ass");
            if (FB) {
                console.log("is broken");
                FB.XFBML.parse(iElement[0]);
            }
        }
    }
});

/* omitted controllers - no issue here.
   two of them are empty, and one correctly updates the scope
   via $scope.$apply(...) for an asynchronous callback */

Application.run(['Application.FBStatusChecker', function(statusChecker){
    statusChecker.updateState();
}]);
```

Let's analyze by parts:

1. The page uses ui-router to switch between application states. This works as expected. Angular is only loaded (i.e. my module being run) once the FB API was successfully loaded.
2. The application defines three states, and in `run()` one of those states is selected.
3. I omitted the controllers, since two are empty, and the third updates -with no issues- the scope.
4. I omitted the state-switcher service methods (this has the task to use `$state` to switch to one of three states depending on facebook state).
5. There's a `directive` named `fbLoginButton`. This directive must be recognized as 'E' (lement), and should match `fb:login-button`. The directive is successfully matched.
6. I had no issue generating the button before using AngularJS and ui-router.

Finally, the templates come:

notloggedin.html

```
<fb:login-button max_rows="1" size="xlarge" show_faces="false" auto_logout_link="false"></fb:login-button>
Debes iniciar sesi&oacute;n en Facebook para continuar.
```

notauthorized.html

```
<fb:login-button max_rows="1" size="xlarge" show_faces="false" auto_logout_link="false"></fb:login-button>
Debes autorizar la aplicaci&oacute;n para continuar.
```

inapp.html

```
<span ng-if="name">
    Bienvenido {{ name }}!
</span>
<span ng-if="!name">
    Listando ...
</span>
```

**Notes**: Also tried HTML5 solution, using div, instead of xfbml.

**And my issue is**: The facebook buttons are not being shown. Only the corresponding texts are being shown. If i'm logged in Facebook when I hit this page, I get correctly redirected to the expected state, with the `{{ name }}` being fetched. The same occurs with the other states, so I'm not having issue specificly with graph api, but with xfbml.

**And my question is**: What am I missing? The directive is being matched but seems that `FM.XML.parse` has no effect. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently -discovered it by a lucky mistake- the `.parse` method ignores the current element, so the parse must start from the parent element. So far, the directive must be changed to:

```
Application.directive("fbLoginButton", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            if (FB) {
                FB.XFBML.parse(iElement[0].parent);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

which consisted in just adding the `.parent` property to get the parent DOM node.

**However**, if two items matched by this directive are siblings (or using another directive with the same functionality), this could be run twice. So recording the element in an array after parsing it, and checking before parsing it, would be a good workaround to avoid doing the parsing twice. Another alternative would be to force a parsing in each state's controller, to the `ui-view`-holding container. The latter would be implemented like this:

1. The only directive will be an attribute-based directive, e.g. `xfbml-parse` in the `ui-view` element (in my case):

   ```
   Application.directive("fbLoginButton", function() {
       return {
           restrict: 'E',
           link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
               if (FB) {
                   FB.XFBML.parse(iElement[0].parent);
               }
           }
       }
   });
   ```

   being no need to implement other directives.
2. After that, use `xfbml-parse` directive in the `ui-view` element. In my case:

   ```
   <div id="content" ui-view xfbml-parse>
       Cargando API de Facebook ...
   </div>
   ```

   which will run the `link` function every time the state changes.
   So: every time the ui-view node renders, the XFBML will be parsed.